# Where is Character Viewer's categorization data saved on OS X?

Tags: macos, unicode, character, categorization

I mean this thing:
[image]

I want to use the same character categorization in my project.

Comment: It's probably based on the Unicode categorisation/character properties. Why don't you go check out the standard?

Comment: It is not the same. I've already checked http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr49/tr49-2.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `/System/Library/Input\ Methods/CharacterPalette.app/Contents/Resources/`, checkout the `Category-*` files.

Comment: You will also find `CharacterDB.sqlite3` (and `RelatedCharDB.sqlite3`) in the resources directory if you need the names of the symbols.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't rely on these files. They are an implementation detail of the Character Palette. In the next OS X release, they might be gone, or have an entirely different format. Instead, use a library designed to be reused, like ICU http://www.icu-project.org/‎